# Dns explanation

Tags: networking, dns

I am new to networking.. Can someone explain to me what is dns>?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming and even if it were it is far too broad to be able to answer it. "Very" would be the short answer to it. You might want to start by reading like Wikipedia article on DNS it should give you a good introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At very-very high level: almost all human beings can only remember names, machines can communicate with IP addresses.

DNS infrastructure can help machines to translate/resolve DNS names to IP address.

In example, without DNS infrastructure you cannot browse on the internet unless you know IP address of the web server.

Todays DNS infra is more important because of geo-redundancy. In example you will connect to an American server from America, and European server from Europe when you browse stackoverflow website.

And I can enumerate many-many other things...